# How to resolve Java LinkageError Exception?

Tags: java, websphere

I am developing an application for WebSphere 6.0 which uses a Java servlet.After deploying and running my application, I am receiving a LinkageError of the following type (from the server log):

Error 500: java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining class: student.operation.Action Could not be defined due to: student/operation/Action (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0) This is often caused by having a class defined at multiple locations within the classloader hierarchy. Other potential causes include compiling against an older or newer version of the class that has an incompatible method signature. Dumping the current context classloader hierarchy: ==> indicates defining classloader ==>[0] com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@666bc7e8 Local ClassPath: E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v6\profiles\WTE_APPSRV61\installedApps\gh-vdikcisv206Node1Cell\DefaultEAR.ear\Student.war\WEB-INF\classes;E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v6\profiles\WTE_APPSRV61\installedApps\gh-vdikcisv206Node1Cell\DefaultEAR.ear\Student.war\WEB-INF\lib\asm.jar;E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v6\profiles\WTE_APPSRV61\installedApps\gh-vdikcisv206Node1Cell\DefaultEAR.ear\Student.war\WEB-INF\lib\c3p0-0.9.0.4.jar;

Comment: it has a pretty good explanation with possible reasons. Did you go through all of them?

Comment: Yes. I understand the problem. My all java classess compiled on java6. So I dont understand why i am getting version problem. I want your help on how to resolve this.

Comment: it appears something is compiled with java 5. Clean your project

Comment: @Bozho, it should be the other way right? Something compiled with java 6 being run on java 5 (or lower)?

Comment: a, yes, I didn't know 50.0 is jdk 6

Answer (score 0):

> LinkageError while defining class: student.operation.Action Could not
>   be defined due to: student/operation/Action (Unsupported major.minor
>   version 50.0)

Class `student.operation.Action` has been compiled under Java 6 (50.0 corresponds to JDK 1.6 compiled class version), but you are using a lower version of JVM/JRE at runtime.

Make sure your runtime environment is also JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nivas answer, Please check whether you are also including the same student.operation.action in any other jars during deployment.

If you are want to run a JDK6 compiled class in JDK5 pass -source  option during compilation.